# How do I pass a req.setHeaders method on res.redirect method within the same app.get function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.json('Enter your query parameters for an image search like so: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=cats&count=10 and for the latest search results enter the url ttps://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/*'); 
});
```

> Here is the app.get method where I want to get parameters input by the user and then redirect it to the bing api to return search results for an image search. The big api requires an API key to be passed into the header, like so Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••. 
>   How do I do this?

```
app.get('/imagesearch/:image*', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.image);
    console.log(req.query.count);
    res.redirect('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q='+req.params.image+'&count='+req.query.count);
});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
   console.log('Express listening on: '+PORT); 
});
```

Comment: You can't set a header that way.  The redirect is telling the browser to go to a specific URL.  The browser will set its own headers when it goes to that URL.  You can't control those headers.  So, what you're asking for is a non-starter.  Can't do it.  You will need to achieve whatever it is you are trying to achieve a different way.  Besides, I don't think you want to pass out your subscription key to any browser that ask you either.

Comment: Do you really want a redirect or do you just want to grab the content at that URL and then return it to the browser as the response to the current request.  If doing it that way, you could set the desired header when you requested the content from within node.js and then you could pipe the response back.  You'd essentially be acting as a proxy for this one result.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yeah, I just want to grab the content from the redirect url to my page, essentially just pipe the data through, yeah. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it now sounds like you just want to fetch the data from the remote site and then return it as the response to the original request, you can do that by using the [`request` module](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers) and then piping the response from that as your response to the original http request.

```
const request = require('request');

app.get('/imagesearch/:image*', function(req, res){
    let options = {
        url: 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q='+req.params.image+'&count='+req.query.count,
        headers: {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxxxx"}
    };
    request(options).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Just a quick question, can I also do this by doing a fs.createReadStream on the bing api url and then piping that response back to the GET request?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun - Not directly.  `fs.createReadStream()` doesn't know how to get the contents of a URL.  That's what the `request()` library is for.  It knows how to get the contents of a URL and turn it into a read stream, set custom headers on the request, handle errors, etc...  The `request()` library creates the read stream for you and puts the contents of the desired URL into that read stream.  You could write your own code to do that, but why?  The request library is already well written, well tested code to do that.

Comment: Okay, I have another quick question in that case. If I want to filter the response received from the request method before piping it back to my main res, I know I can use the underscore library for that. How do i pipe my response from the request into a variable or a file. I tried fs.createWriteStream(object_variable) in place of res as the pipe parameter, but that didn't work.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun - You have lots of choices.  This is really the subject of another question.  The most elegant way would be to use a transform stream object.  You'd pipe the `request()` stream into your transform object which would output a modified stream that could then be piped into the response.  You could get the whole `request()` into memory, modify it and then send the modified data as the response.  You could save the data to a file by piping it to a write stream as in `request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))`, modify the data and so on...

Comment: @ZaidHumayun - FYI, here's a good article on streams and transform streams: http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html#what_are_transform_streams_