# External API Calls With Express, Node.JS and Require Module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route as followed:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search',
    qs: {
      api_key: '123456',
      query: 'World of Warcraft: Legion'
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body)
      }
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm trying to make an API call to the Giant Bomb API to bring back whatever data it has about World of Warcraft.

The problem is, the route just loads; it doesn't do anything or it doesn't time out, it's just continuous loading.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but that being said... I don't know what's right either.  I'm trying to learn as I go along.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: The first answer should give you some clue as to what's going on... but, can you elaborate on "it's just continuous loading"? By that, do you mean the request never finishes? The route never resolves? Do you get any indication that this is actually the case? Or are you just not getting a response?

Comment: What does `qs` stand for in your request?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to take the data you get from `request()` and send it back as the response to the original web server request.  It was just continuously loading because you never sent any sort of response to the original request, thus the browser was just sitting there waiting for a response to come back and eventually, it will time out.

Since `request()` supports streams, you can send back the data as the response very simply using `.pipe()` like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search',
    qs: {
      api_key: '123456',
      query: 'World of Warcraft: Legion'
    }
  }).pipe(res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This will `.pipe()` the `request()` result into the `res` object and it will become the response to the original http request.

Related answer here: [How to proxy request back as response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284773/how-do-i-pass-a-req-setheaders-method-on-res-redirect-method-within-the-same-app/39285150#39285150)

---

**Edit in 2021.**  The `request()` library has now been deprecated and is no longer recommended for new code.  There are many [alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) to choose from.  My favorite is the `got()` library.  The above could be accomplished using it like this.  This also upgrades to use the `pipeline()` function which is a better version of `.pipe()` with more complete error handling.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const got = require('got');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  const dataStream = got.stream({
      uri: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search',
      qs: {
        api_key: '123456',
        query: 'World of Warcraft: Legion'
      }
  });
  pipeline(dataStream, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.sendStatus(500);
      }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Great answer. I am trying to use a similar setup but I also want to use Node `apicache` and having said that `apicache` works well with `express` this setup would help the middleware cache the external API response.

Comment: `request` was deprecated Feb 11th 2020.

Comment: @JaydeepMor - I added a version of the answer using the `got()` library.

Answer (score 8):

For Laravel users,

First of all install `npm i axios` package if not.

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
    /* Your settings here like Accept / Headers etc. */
}

axios.get('http://local.dev/api/v1/users', config)
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
});
```

Hopefully it will help someone!

Answer (score 4):

Per every route in Express, it is necessary to send a response (partial or complete) or call `next`, or do both. Your route handler does neither. Try

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search',
    qs: {
      api_key: '123456',
      query: 'World of Warcraft: Legion'
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
        res.json(body);
      } else {
        res.json(error);
      }
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and see what data this route handler responds with.

Comment: Thanks for the input but unfortunately I'm getting the same result.  If I let the page load long enough, I get an error saying the page doesn't work, and it didn't send anything.

Comment: I tried to follow this solution but "Request" module has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

**In 2022**

In node

```js
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch')
  .then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));

app.get('/checkDobleAPI', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const apiResponse = await fetch(
     'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    const apiResponseJson = await apiResponse.json()

    console.log(apiResponseJson)
    res.send('Running ')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
  }
})
```