# How to call another api via express?

Tags: node.js, express

My goal is to put `http://localhost:3000/test` into my browser and get the response from `http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test`.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd) to setup Express, mongoose (although the final version of this will not connect to Mongo, only the VM's endpoints), etc. I produced a to-do list API, and it works as expected.

However, I can't figure out how to call my VM with this API.

I read "[External API Calls With Express, Node.JS and Require Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301227/external-api-calls-with-express-node-js-and-require-module)", and came up with the following addition to server.js:

```
router = express.Router(),
request = require('request');

router.get("/test", function(req,res,next){
    request({
        uri: 'http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test/',
    }).pipe(res)
})
```

> But, when I put `http://localhost:3000/test` into my browser I get a 404 error in the console.

Here's a **[PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/nL0Y71whACJZk3tu9unI?p=catalogue)** of all my code. `server.js` contains the changes I have made to try to get this to work.

I'm an Express noob, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Did try cURL for your vm?

Comment: @Dinesh If I go to `http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test` from my browser, I get the expected results, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the router to the express app instance. This can be done using

```
app.use('/test', router);
```

The above line tells `express` to route all requests to `/test` to your router instance.

And inside your router, since you already specified the path, you should change the `get` function to

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     request({
         uri: 'http://my_virtual_machine:8080/rest/stuff/test/',
     }).pipe(res)
});
```