# NodeJS/ExpressJS - Send response of http request back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a website using Angular 2 and I am using node.js as backend.

I managed to send a request from the angular client to the node.js server and forwarded this from node.js to another application via an HTTP request. My goal is now to send the response from the third application back to the angular client page (I managed also to get the response from the third application), but I am a newbie in node js/express and I couldn't manage to get the response body out of the HTTP request and send it back to the angular client.

In the nodejs server I have following code (mostly by looking into tutorials):

```
app.route('/api/test').post((req, res) => {
   postCode(JSON.stringify(req.body));
   //Here I want to send back the response from the third application
   //to the Angular client (instead of 'Hi')
   res.status(200).send('Hi');
});

function postCode(post_data) {

const post_options = {
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: '8080',
   path: '/test',
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
   }
};

// Set up the request
const post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
   res.setEncoding('utf8');
   let responseString = ''
   res.on('data', function (data) {
      responseString += data;
      console.log('Response data: ' + responseString);
   });
   res.on("end", function (data) {
      responseString += data;
      console.log('Response end: ' + responseString);
   });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.end();
}
```

So, how can I manage now to "use" the response of the HTTP request and send it back in the app.route('/api/arq')?post method to the angular client (Please see also first comment in code)?

Thank you very much and

Kind regards,
Yasemin

Comment: This seems like a pretty common pattern to me. Maybe this has been answered here already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301227/external-api-calls-with-express-node-js-and-require-module

Comment: Do I have to put the pipe behind the http.request, because this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: seems like this similar pattern was answered already - [External API Calls With Express, Node.JS and Require Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301227/external-api-calls-with-express-node-js-and-require-module) thanks to @madflow for finding it.

First of all you're doing some extra work in my opinion, why not use a framework like express.js?

Anyhow - what I would do is send the request to your third party from within the `/api/arq` endpoint, call the `http.request` after receiving a request inside the route and inside `res.on("end"...` pass the answer along.

Comment: I thought, that I am already using expressjs? How can I pass the answer in res.on("end")? I already tried res.send at this place but it didn't work.

Comment: As already stated before, this doesn't work. I get the error message "Unresolved function or method status()"

Comment: Thx JBK. This was the solution.

Comment: @Yasemin K. Happy to help, would appreciate it if you marked my answer as the correct one 

Comment: ...and good job on not giving up and actually solving it after a few days!! 

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   console.log('Response end: ' + responseString);
> ```

The above line is the point where you have the data you want to send in your response.

So send the response *there*, and not immediately after you call `postCode`.